# Program does not appear to run and does not flag any errors

Tags: java, swing

While trying to compile a 'Guess the Number' program in Netbeans the programme seems to keep on running but the programme is not executing. When the user clicks the 'Play' JButton the playGame method should run but nothing seems too happen and no exception is thrown.

Code is below.
Thanks
Ciaran

```
 /*
 * chpter 11 GUI programmong questions
 * 11.15
 */
package Chapter11GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.ActiveEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessGame extends JFrame {
    //instance varibles/files

    private JLabel intro;
    private JLabel highorlow;
    private JButton play;
    private JTextField enterAnswer;
    private int answer1;
    private int answer2;
    private ImageIcon icon1;
    private ImageIcon icon2;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Random numberGenerator;
    private int correctAnswer;

    //constructor willll create GUI o a JFrame and register event handlers
    public GuessGame() {
        super("GuessGAme");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bug1.gif"));
        Icon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("travelbug.gif"));

        //JtextField to get user input
        enterAnswer = new JTextField(5);
        //enterAnswer.addActionListener(handler);
        enterAnswer.setText("Guess");
        enterAnswer.setEditable(false);

        //JLabel to display heading
        intro = new JLabel("Press Play to begin....", icon1, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        highorlow = new JLabel();

        //place componments on a panel useing flowlayout manager to hold text aea only

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(enterAnswer);
        panel.add(highorlow);


        //JButton to play again and use anoumonus class to call gameMethod
        play = new JButton("Play");
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(intro, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //if button clicked then setart game

                play.setText("Enjoy");
                playGame();

                //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }//end actionPerfomred
        });//end annmous class ActionListener call from addAcionlistener method

    }//end construtor

    //a method to play the game
    public void playGame() {

        //generate randown number bewteen 1 and 100
        numberGenerator = new Random();
        correctAnswer = numberGenerator.nextInt(100);
        panel.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        answer1 = 0;
        answer2 = 0;
        enterAnswer.setEditable(true);
        enterAnswer.setText("");

        while ((answer1 != correctAnswer) && (answer2 != correctAnswer)) {

            intro.setText("I have a number bewteen 1 and a 100."
                    + "Can you guess my number?");
            enterAnswer.setEditable(true);
            enterAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == enterAnswer) {
                        answer1 = Integer.parseInt(enterAnswer.getText());
                    }




                    //set background as red as it is first guess
                    panel.setBackground(Color.red);

                    //noe set wether too high or two low
                    if (answer1 > correctAnswer) {
                        highorlow.setText("Guess Too High");
                        highorlow.setIcon(icon2);

                    } else if (answer1 < correctAnswer) {
                        highorlow.setText("You are gussing too low");
                        highorlow.setIcon(icon2);

                    }//end esle if statement
                }//end actionPerfomred
            });//end ActionListener

            //get answer number 2
            intro.setText("Try Again...");
            enterAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == enterAnswer) {
                        answer2 = Integer.parseInt(enterAnswer.getText());
                    }



                    //check if gettingb hot or cold
                    //2nd answer is closer than first so turn red
                    if ((Math.abs(answer2 - correctAnswer)) > (Math.abs(answer2 -              correctAnswer))) {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
                    } else {
                        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                    //now add too hihg ot tewo low
                    //noe set wether too high or two low
                    if (answer2 > correctAnswer) {
                        highorlow.setText("Guess Too High");
                        highorlow.setIcon(icon2);

                    } else if (answer2 < correctAnswer) {
                        highorlow.setText("You are gussing too low");
                        highorlow.setIcon(icon2);

                    }//end esle if statement

                }//end actionPerformed
            });//end ActionLIstener

        }//end while loop when answer is correct
        //what to do if answer is correct
        panel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        enterAnswer.setText("Correct!!");
        enterAnswer.setEditable(false);
        play.setText("PLay Again?");




    }//end method playGame
}//end class

/*
 *chapter 11
 * porgramming question 11.14
 */
package Chapter11GUI;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GuessGameTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // instanistae frame form GuessGAme
        GuessGame frame = new GuessGame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
    }//end main
}//end clas test
```

Thanks. Have removed the while loop and programme is now running, but not as I intended. To troubleshoot I am using the netbeans debugger, the problem I have is I cannot seem to step into the playGame() method to see exactly what is going wrong. Have tried using step in (F7) at the anonymous ActionListener innerclass assoc with JButton to access playGame(), and also I have pointed the cursor at beginning of playGame and then Run To Cursor command. In both instances the debugger returns to the test application main class. Hope that made sense...

Have tried inserting a breakpoint at the playGame() but could not access. Could this be something to do with the playGame() method not been part of a java main class?? I can only seem to access the constructor of a class from a main class when the class in question is instaniated.....

Comment: It's not easy to help you without an error or something observable to go on. You don't have any clues what goes wrong?

Comment: Your question is incorrect since your class *is* in fact compiling. Please fix this.

Comment: Posting a wall of code and expecting us to read through it is a bit much. YOU have to try some debugging yourself. If you can't even do that, then you shouldn't be programming.

Comment: *"Program does not compile and does not flag any errors"* Er, no, that doesn't happen. If compilation fails, you'll get an error saying why.

Comment: @Marc B : Thanks for feedback very useful indeed, i have tried to debug but but my experience is limited here as i am new to programming. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program *is* in fact compiling and in fact appears to be running as well, but it looks like you're tying up the Swing event thread with a `while (true)` loop.

```
public void playGame() {

    //generate randown number bewteen 1 and 100
    numberGenerator = new Random();

    // .... etc...

    // ***** this will lock your GUI!! *******
    while ((answer1 != correctAnswer) && (answer2 != correctAnswer)) {

        intro.setText("I have a number bewteen 1 and a 100."
                + "Can you guess my number?");
        // ....
    }

}//end method playGame
```

When you do this, the while loop will continue running on the Swing event thread (or event dispatch thread or edt), preventing the edt from interacting with the user. This will cause the program to be completely non-responsive.

The solution, don't do this. Use event-driven programming code not linear console program code for your project. Have your program change it's behaviors based on the state of the answer1 and answer2 fields, but don't do this in a while loop. In other words, have the ActionListener's actionPerformed method behave differently depending on the state of these and other class fields. The Swing event loop will be all the game loop that you'll need.

Comment: Thanks. Have removed the while loop and programme is now running, but not as I intended. To troubleshoot I am using the netbeans debugger, the problem I have is I cannot seem to step into the playGame() method to see exactly what is going wrong. Have tried using step in (F7) at the anonymous ActionListener innerclass assoc with JButton  to access playGame(), and also I have pointed the cursor at beginning of playGame and then Run To Cursor command. In both instances the debugger returns to the test application main class. Hope that made sense...

Comment: @dancingbush: You should have the debugger mark a line of code as interest as a breakpoint so that it will stop when that line is reached. For more help, post updated code and information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, accessed the method thru the JButton actionListener anonymous class by using a GUI snapshot in the debugger.

Thanks again for the help.
C